# CSS background full length but not full width

Tags: css, background

On my new webpage (http://patrick-ott.de/ -- it is getting there ;), I seem to have encountered a problem. At the very end there is a promise for a non black/white-version but it does not show the fully colored image. That is fine, I do not want the background to scale in width (or maybe when the resolution of the display exceeds the one of the image) but I do want to see the full-length version of the background, so essentially you can keep scrolling longer. Any ideas on how to do this smart? Right now the CSS for the background is as simple as this:

```
.colorbox {    
  background-image: url(pictures/colorbackground.jpg); 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; }
```

Comment: how do you want your background to look like

Comment: basically have the possibility to scroll down in Y direction to the end of the background (it is huge) but the X-direction should be kept to the screen-size.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
background-repeat: round round;
```

That should do the trick. But this is a pretty new feature in CSS so it will work if you expect your users to be using IE9+ and other modern browsers.

Comment: Worth noting that it is only supported by IE9+ and Opera 10.5+, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Is `background-repeat` supported by Chrome? (Considering it's the most downloaded non-built-in browser)

Comment: Sorry, does not even work in chrome. It now shows the lower end of the image.

Answer (score 0):

set `background-size`

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```